# Keep Leading zeros C

Tags: c, getline, scanf

I am trying to read the memory addresses from /proc//maps and I use the following code

```
for (ptr = NULL; getline(&ptr, &n, file) > 0;)     {
   if (ptr[0]== ' ') { continue; }
   sscanf(ptr, "%lx-%lx", &r0, &r1);
   printf("r0: %lx, r1: %lx\n", r0, r1);           }
```

Assume that file points to /proc//maps & ptr is the line pointer. But when you consider a maps file, it doesn't read the file proper. It drops the zero, it does not pick the zeros up. So consider:

```
00110000-00123000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 129925     /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl-2.11.1.so
```

After running through my program:

```
r0: 110000, r1: 123000
```

How I keep the leading zeros to output something like this:

```
r0: 00110000, r1: 00123000
```

Edit: The printf is for debugging.

Here is what I do with r1 later on

```
mem = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, mem_fd, r1)
```

Comment: Do you need r0 an r1 as numbers - perhaps you can just treat the data as strings

Comment: That looks like Python disguised as C :)

Answer (score 2):

You're reading these values into integers; integers don't have leading zeros.

If you know how many digits you want to pad out the length to, you can specify that in your format string:

```
printf("r0: %08lx, r1: %08lx\n", r0, r1);
```

There's no way to store and recall the exact number of leading zeroes without storing the value in a different format (e.g, a string), though.

Comment: Atleast they are 32 bit addresses so at max I might have 8 leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `0` flag (which specifies leading zeros), followed by the padded length.

```
printf("r0: %08lx, r1: %08lx\n", r0, r1);
             ^^         ^^
```

**[This link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)** is a good reference to look at.